# How to make box2d mouse joint works similar to box2d setposition

Tags: box2d, cocos2d-iphone

I want to make b2mouse joint working similar to b2setposition, though i know in mouse joint force is applied, so it's not possible to reach the desired point without any delay like setPosition(), but i want to make it works as close as b2setPosition(). So on which mousejoint/body properties should i work on so that it acts as close as b2setposition.

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can look how MouseJoint is implemented and make some changes to it or create your own joint, to make it work the way you need.

Comment: yea i know it, but i want to know which property???Or there is any example anywhere???

Comment: Look at SetMaxForce property, the more it is quicklier body moves. And damping it will not allow body to bounce around your mouse. But when you have huge your moving object can collide other object and to make some unexpected behaviour